# query json document SQL Server

Tags: json, azure-sql-database

I'm trying read data from a json document stored on azure data lake storage from an Azure SQL database using the below query. I tried a couple of ways and nothing seems to bring the data back. I tried using this `'$.data[0].AccID'` in `OPENJSON` for instance and brings back only the first record from multiple arrays but, not sure how to bring back all the data.

**json:**

```
[
    {
        "data":  [
                      {
                          "AccID":  1234,
                          "CustID":  456,
                          "Total":  1234.1234,
                          "OrderDate":  "2022-12-01"
                      },
                      {
                          "AccID":  5678,
                          "CustID":  890,
                          "Total":  5678.5678,
                          "OrderDate":  "2022-12-01"
                      }
                  ],
        "count":  2
    },
    {
        "data":  [
                      {
                          "AccID":  1234,
                          "CustID":  456,
                          "Total":  100.0,
                          "OrderDate":  "2021-12-01"
                      },
                      {
                          "AccID":  5678,
                          "CustID":  890,
                          "Total":  200.0,
                          "OrderDate":  "2021-12-01"
                      },
                      {
                          "AccID":  8900,
                          "CustID":  235,
                          "Total":  300.0,
                          "OrderDate":  "2021-12-01"
                      }
                  ],
        "count":  3
    }   
]
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'blobpath/file.json', 
    DATA_SOURCE = 'adls',
    SINGLE_CLOB
     ) AS [data]
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (X.BulkColumn, '$.value')
    WITH (
    AccID int,
    CustID int,
    Total float,
    OrderDate date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created storage account and uploaded Json file into container,
[reference  image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVPFN.png)

input .json:

```
[
    {
        "data":  [
                      {
                          "AccID":  1234,
                          "CustID":  456,
                          "Total":  1234.1234,
                          "OrderDate":  "2022-12-01"
                      },
                      {
                          "AccID":  5678,
                          "CustID":  890,
                          "Total":  5678.5678,
                          "OrderDate":  "2022-12-01"
                      }
                  ],
        "count":  2
    },
    {
        "data":  [
                      {
                          "AccID":  1234,
                          "CustID":  456,
                          "Total":  100.0,
                          "OrderDate":  "2021-12-01"
                      },
                      {
                          "AccID":  5678,
                          "CustID":  890,
                          "Total":  200.0,
                          "OrderDate":  "2021-12-01"
                      },
                      {
                          "AccID":  8900,
                          "CustID":  235,
                          "Total":  300.0,
                          "OrderDate":  "2021-12-01"
                      }
                  ],
        "count":  3
    }   
]
```

I generated sas token and created masterkey and data source. I created a table in sql with following columns

```
Create  table data1( ACCID varchar(100),               
          CustID varchar(100),
          Total float(100),                
          OrderDate date,
          count int  )
```

Insert data into that table using below code:

```
INSERT  INTO data1
SELECT ACCID,CustID,Total,OrderDate,count FROM  OPENROWSET(
BULK  'jsonfile path',
DATA_SOURCE = 'your data source'
SINGLE_CLOB
) AS DataFile
cross  apply openjson(BulkColumn)
WITH (
      AccID varchar(100) '$.data[0].AccID',               
          CustID varchar(100) '$.data[0].CustID',
          Total float '$.data[0].Total',                
          OrderDate date '$.data[0].OrderDate',
          count int '$.count'
)
INSERT  INTO data1
SELECT ACCID,CustID,Total,OrderDate,count FROM  OPENROWSET(
BULK  'jsonfile path',
DATA_SOURCE = 'your data source'
SINGLE_CLOB
) AS DataFile
cross  apply openjson(BulkColumn)
WITH (
      AccID varchar(100) '$.data[1].AccID',               
          CustID varchar(100) '$.data[1].CustID',
          Total float '$.data[1].Total',                
          OrderDate date '$.data[1].OrderDate',
          count int '$.count'
)
         
INSERT  INTO data1
SELECT ACCID,CustID,Total,OrderDate,count FROM  OPENROWSET(
BULK  'jsonfile path',
DATA_SOURCE = 'your data source'
SINGLE_CLOB
) AS DataFile
cross  apply openjson(BulkColumn)
WITH (
          AccID varchar(100) '$.data[2].AccID',               
          CustID varchar(100) '$.data[2].CustID',
          Total float '$.data[2].Total',                
          OrderDate date '$.data[2].OrderDate',
          count int '$.count'
)
```

Data is inserted successfully.
I retrieved the data of table I got as below

[image]

I deleted the Null values row using below code
Image for reference:

```
delete from data1 where ACCID is Null
```

I retrieved the data of table order by count according to the json using below code

```
select * from data1 order by count
```

Output:

[image]

In this way I retrieve all the data from Json document.